# Akka Ask keeps timing out in a merge sort implementation

Tags: scala, merge, akka, future

I'm a complete beginner in Akka and Scala. As one of my first projects I decided to make an implementation of merge sort where instead of recursion I instantiate new actors that do the splitting and merging. It seems that my system reaches the leaves of the merge sort tree, and even some merging takes place, however then it stops and I get an AskTimeoutException. I had a similar problem in another Ask-related project. Can someone point me in the right direction?

ParentMerger receive implementation:

```
def receive = {
    case ParentMerger.Begin => {
      implicit var timeout = Timeout(60.seconds)
      println("Parent sending off first halves")
      // Assumption: at the beginning the array size is 2 or greater
      var arrayFuture1 = mergers(0) ? ParentMerger.SendHalf(array.slice(0, array.length/2))
      var arrayFuture2 = mergers(1) ? ParentMerger.SendHalf(array.slice(array.length/2, array.length))

      arrayFuture1.onComplete {
        case Success(Merger.Reply(arr1: ArrayBuffer[Int])) => {
          arrayFuture2.onComplete {
            case Success(Merger.Reply(arr2: ArrayBuffer[Int])) => {
              print(merge(arr1, arr2).toString())
              println("Final merge done")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Merger receive implementation:

```
    def receive = {
    case ParentMerger.SendHalf(array: ArrayBuffer[Int]) if array.length == 1 => {
      println("Child received array of size 1")
      sender() ! Merger.Reply(array)
    }
    case ParentMerger.SendHalf(array: ArrayBuffer[Int]) if array.length >= 2 => {
      println("Child received an array of size >= 2")
      for(i <- 0 to 1) {
        mergers(i) = context.actorOf(Props[Merger])
      }

      implicit var timeout = Timeout(60.seconds)
      var arrayFuture1 = mergers(0) ? ParentMerger.SendHalf(array.slice(0, array.length/2))
      var arrayFuture2 = mergers(1) ? ParentMerger.SendHalf(array.slice(array.length/2, array.length))

      arrayFuture1.onComplete {
        case Success(Merger.Reply(arr1: ArrayBuffer[Int])) => {
          arrayFuture2.onComplete {
            case Success(Merger.Reply(arr2: ArrayBuffer[Int])) => {
              println("Child merge")
              sender() ! Merger.Reply(merge(arr1, arr2))
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The output that I get:

```
    Parent sending off first halves
Child received an array of size >= 2
Child received an array of size >= 2
Child received an array of size >= 2
Child received an array of size >= 2
Child received array of size 1
Child received array of size 1
Child received an array of size >= 2
Child received an array of size >= 2
Child received array of size 1
Child received an array of size >= 2
Child received array of size 1
Child received array of size 1
Child received array of size 1
Child received an array of size >= 2
Child received array of size 1
Child received array of size 1
Child merge
Child merge
Child received array of size 1
Child merge
Child merge
Child received array of size 1
[INFO] [02/14/2017 08:35:32.412] [Main-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-13] [akka://Main/deadLetters] Message [Merger$Reply] from Actor[akka://Main/user/app/$a/$b/$b#-1137516511] to Actor[akka://Main/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [02/14/2017 08:35:32.412] [Main-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-13] [akka://Main/deadLetters] Message [Merger$Reply] from Actor[akka://Main/user/app/$b/$a#2073409209] to Actor[akka://Main/deadLetters] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [02/14/2017 08:35:32.412] [Main-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-13] [akka://Main/deadLetters] Message [Merger$Reply] from Actor[akka://Main/user/app/$a/$a#-1459967586] to Actor[akka://Main/deadLetters] was not delivered. [3] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [02/14/2017 08:35:32.412] [Main-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-13] [akka://Main/deadLetters] Message [Merger$Reply] from Actor[akka://Main/user/app/$b/$b/$b#-2142577608] to Actor[akka://Main/deadLetters] was not delivered. [4] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
scala.MatchError: Failure(akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://Main/user/app/$a#520493765]] after [60000 ms]. Sender[Actor[akka://Main/user/app#1966408365]] sent message of type "ParentMerger$SendHalf".) (of class scala.util.Failure)
    at ParentMerger$$anonfun$receive$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(ParentMerger.scala:67)
    at ParentMerger$$anonfun$receive$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$adapted(ParentMerger.scala:66)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replying to the wrong actor:

```
sender() ! Merger.Reply(merge(arr1, arr2))
```

When called from inside the response to a future will probably not work. Capture the `sender` outside your `onComplete` blocks:

```
  val originalSender = sender()
  arrayFuture1.onComplete {
    case Success(Merger.Reply(arr1: ArrayBuffer[Int])) => {
      arrayFuture2.onComplete {
        case Success(Merger.Reply(arr2: ArrayBuffer[Int])) => {
          println("Child merge")
          originalSender  ! Merger.Reply(merge(arr1, arr2))
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It fixed it. Thank you! So, if I put sender() in the onComplete block, will it be referring to the sender of Merger.Reply?

Comment: It's not obvious to me at all exactly what it is. It could be *your* actor (i.e. `self`) but the double-nested `onComplete` blocks makes me think it's probably some subsystem actor that you wouldn't even have access to

I've learnt that it's generally best to avoid the `ask` pattern for this reason: it's really susceptible to *apparently innocent* refactorings resulting in cryptically (and silently) failing code.